# Android SQLite rawQuery() method

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I created a table with three columns `id`, `name` and `discipline`.
I want to find the student name given the `discipline`.

Following is my method:

```
String findstudent(String disc){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String find = "SELECT * FROM  "+ TABLE_STUDENTS + " WHERE "+KEY_DISCIPLINE +" = " +disc ;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(find,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String found =cursor.getString(1);

    return  found;
}
```

When I use it, the application stops working.

Comment: If Your app stops working then check and post Logcat output here.

Comment: For a start, call cursor.close() when you've finished with it.

Comment: thnx,still not working..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure. But, you can try this way

```
Cursor.moveToFirst();

do{

//get the data

String found =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("COLUMN NAME"));

}while(Cursor.moveNext);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
String find = "SELECT *<enter code here> 
               FROM  "+ TABLE_STUDENTS + " 
               WHERE "+KEY_DISCIPLINE +" = '" + disc + "'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String findstudent(String disc){

    Cursor cursor;

    cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_STUDENTS,null, KEY_DISCIPLINE +" = "+ disc, null, null, null, null,null );

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String found =cursor.getString(0);

    return  found;
}
```

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor findstudent(String disc){
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
String[] find = new String[]{ col1,col2,col3};//all fields in db in need
String order=col1;
Cursor c=db.query(TABLE_STUDENTS, find, KEY_DISCIPLINE +" = " +disc, null, null, null, order);
 c.moveToFirst();
    db.close();
    return c;
}
```

In the activity include this:

```
DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
try {
        Cursor c = db.displayName(your_disc);

        startManagingCursor(c);

        if (!c.moveToFirst()) {
            System.out.println("!Move " + posnumber);

        } else {
            String idname = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(DataBaseHandler.KEY_NAME));
            System.out.println("null:");
            System.out.println("Move " + idname);
            return true;
        }
        c.close();
        stopManagingCursor(c);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```